# Connecting to .onion network with python

Tags: python, proxy, tor

I want make python to get into .onion sites from console, below example can use tor in python  but when i try to connect to .onion sites it gives error such as "Name or service not known", how do i fix this ?

Sample Code:

```
import socket
import socks
import httplib

def connectTor():
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5,"127.0.0.1",9050,True)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    print "Connected to tor"

def newIdentity():
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    socks.setdefaultproxy()
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST,9051))
    s.send("AUTHENTICATE\r\n")
    response = s.recv(128)
    if response.startswith("250"):
        s.send("SIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n"),
    s.close()
    connectTor()

def readPage(page):
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(page)
    conn.request("GET","/")
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print (response.read())

def main():
    connectTor()
    print "Tor Ip Address :"
    readPage("my-ip.heroku.com")
    print "\n\n"
    readPage("od6j46sy5zg7aqze.onion")
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The most likely problem is that the DNS resolution is happening outside of SOCKS. So, "my-ip.heroku.com" works fine, because your normal name resolver and your TOR proxy both resolve it to the same IP, but "od6j46sy5zg7aqze.onion" can't be resolved by your normal name resolver. That wouldn't answer your question, but would help you focus the debugging, so a good first step is to confirm that or rule it out.

Comment: Also, which socks module are you using. At least two of them have the same runtime module name, `socks`, that you've imported.

Comment: Actually, I think I can guess the problem here. You're monkeypatching `socket.socket`, but not `socket.getaddrinfo`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is your problem, but I may be wrong.

You're relying on monkeypatching `socket.socket` to force `HTTPConnection` to use your SOCKS5 proxy to talk to TOR. But `HTTPConnection` calls `socket.create_connection`, which in turns calls `socket.getaddrinfo` to resolve the name before calling `socket.socket` to create the socket. And `getaddrinfo` doesn't use `socket`. So, it's not patched, so it's not talking to your SOCKS5 proxy, so it's using your default name resolver.

This works fine for proxying connections to normal internet hosts, because TOR is going to return the same DNS result for "my-ip.heroku.com" as your normal name resolver. But it won't work for "od6j46sy5zg7aqze.onion", because there is no .onion TLD in your normal name resolver.

If you're curious, you can see the source to [`HTTPConnection.connect`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/httplib.py#l769), [`socket.create_connection`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/socket.py#l537), and [`getaddrinfo`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/socketmodule.c) (the last in C, and scattered throughout the module depending on your platform).

So, how do you solve this? Well, looking at two of the SOCKS5 modules that are called `socks`, one has a function that could be directly monkeypatched in place of `create_connection` (its API is not identical, but it's close enough for what `HTTPConnection` needs); the other doesn't, but you could pretty easily write one (just call `socks.socksocket` and then call its `connect` method). Or you could modify `HTTPConnection` to create a `socket.socket` and call its `connect` method.

Finally, you may be wondering why most of the different `socks` modules have a `setdefaultproxy` function that with a parameter named `remote_dns` that specifically claims it causes DNS resolving to be performed remotely, when that doesn't actually work. Well, it *does* work if you use a `socks.socksocket`, but it can't possibly work if you use `socket.getaddrinfo`.

By the way, if you haven't read [DnsResolver](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/DnsResolver) and [TorifyHOWTO](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO), read them before going any further, because just trying to slap together code that works without knowing why it works is almost guaranteed to lead to you (or your users) leaking information when you thought you were being anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

You can add port 80 to the onion address to avoid DNS look up.
e.g. readPage("od6j46sy5zg7aqze.onion:80")

with urllib2 you need to specify also the protocol (i.e. http)
e.g.

import urllib2

print urllib2.urlopen("http://od6j46sy5zg7aqze.onion:80").read()