# Fetching a .onion domain with requests

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2, socks

I'm trying to access the following domain `nzxj65x32vh2fkhk.onion` using requests.
I have tor running and I configured the session's object proxies correctly.

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://localhost:9050',
                   'https': 'socks5://localhost:9050'}
print(session.get('http://httpbin.org/ip').text) # prints {"origin": "67.205.146.164" }

print(requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip').text) # prints {"origin": "5.102.254.76" }
```

However when I try to access the URL with the .onion domain I get the following error:

```
session.get('http://nzxj65x32vh2fkhk.onion/all')

ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPConnectionPool(host='nzxj65x32vh2fkhk.onion', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /all (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSConnection object at 0x7f5e8c2dbbd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

I also tried to replace `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` as suggested in one of the answers. The result is the same unfortunately.

Performing the same request using urllib2 works just fine.

```
import socks, socket, urllib2

def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
  sock = socks.socksocket()
  sock.connect(address)
  return sock

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '127.0.0.1', 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection

print(urllib2.urlopen('http://nzxj65x32vh2fkhk.onion/all').read()) # Prints the URL's contents
```

cURL also retrieves the contents of the page correctly.

I'm using Python 2.7.13, requests 2.13.0 & PySocks 1.6.7. Tor is running through a docker container with the following command:

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8118:8118 -p 9050:9050 -d dperson/torproxy
```

What am I doing wrong here? What do I need to do to make requests recognize the .onion URLs?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14988105/2689986

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil But I am able to resolve the DNS with urllib2 without monkeypatching getaddrinfo. Also, that answer doesn't say how to do so.

Comment: But you *are* creating a `socket` connection prior to fetching the url in your `urllib2` example, which is not the case with `requests`. You probably have to bridge that gap, no idea how.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is to use the `socks5h` protocol in order to enable remote DNS resolving in case the local DNS resolving process fails. [See https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/e3f89bf23c53b98593e4248054661472aacac820/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/socks.py#L158](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/e3f89bf23c53b98593e4248054661472aacac820/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/socks.py#L158)

The following code works as expected:

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5h://localhost:9050',
                   'https': 'socks5h://localhost:9050'}
print(session.get('http://httpbin.org/ip').text) # prints {"origin": "67.205.146.164" }

print(requests.get('http://httpbin.org/ip').text) # prints {"origin": "5.102.254.76" }

print(session.get('http://nzxj65x32vh2fkhk.onion/all').text) # Prints the contents of the page
```